# can i use setInterval function twice in a .hover()?

Tags: jquery, hover, setinterval

can i use setInterval twice in .hover()? is yes how is it possible??

wht i have in .hover is::

```
  var target = evt.target; 

      if (target.timer) {
        clearTimeout(target.timer);
        target.timer = null;
      }
      target.timer =  setInterval(function() {  
                    $('.'+item).addClass(item+'-    over2');},
                    500,
                    function() {$('.'+item).removeClass(item+'-over2');},1000);$('.'+item).addClass(item+'-over1');
```

Now inside this hover, i need to set another time delay  to remove both classes -over1 and -over2

How is this possible??

Any help is highly appreciable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use several setTimeout or setIntervall after each other, but each will return it's own handler so you need seperate variables to store them if you need to reference them.

But remember, setIntervall starts a repeating call to the method that will be called repeatedly every intervall.

So for hiding some popup you probably want setTimeout.

Alternative jQuery methods:

http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

Comment: how to use settimeout ?? . I tried using setInterval twice in .hover(), but goes on infinite loop, how to use setInterval twice in the above senario. Also, it needs to come out of infinite loop. you can view it here,http://andmine.com/clients/moxie/index.php?page=home . In the banner, hover on the book image..

Comment: Are you using jQuerym then you could probably use their animation queue. Check the added links in my response and see if any of those methods is usefull.

Comment: But otherwize, you could just have the first setTimeout end with setting another timeout or just have the first cod3e set two different timeouts. But if you need more help please explain what you are trying to achieve and skip the code.

Comment: I am using jQuery version 1.3.2 . I cannot modify my jQuery version as it affects my other code. The above code sets interval of .5 sec after it loads image-over1 and then loads image-over2. Then it clears the timer when image-over2 is loaded . Now what i need is after it loads the second image, it should load the third image with time interval  of .5sec on hover. I could not set time interval to load third image. Plz help me with the code in ref to above code.